# Disable auto change layout direction while using android:supportsRTL="true"

Tags: android, android-layout, multiple-languages, rtl-language

My application must support both RTL and LTR languages in the future **but for now just RTLs**. When I use `android:supportsRTL="true"` with `android:layoutDirection="end"` in each layout, NavigationView and Toolbar and everything else are fine.

But the only problem is when user change system language to a LTR language everything goes wrong because of layout direction changing.

**WHAT I NEED**:  I have to set supportsRTL:"true". I need to change layout direction programmatically when user choose the "application" language at startup and not according to OS language.

**QUESTION**: Is there any way to prevent auto changing of layout direction by changing the OS language (not by setting supportsRTL false)?

See image below:

[image: supportsRTL="true", RTL vs LTR]

If I set `android:supportRTL="false"` and just design layouts for RTL, Toolbar and Navigation's menu direction will be my new troubles.

See image below:

[image: supportsRTL="false"]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Solved**. It was just a tiny horrible mistake.

But for anyone who has some problem like that I had this going to work very vell on android version **17 or above**, for pre 17 I think the only way is to use separate layouts for RTL and LTR.

If you have to use `android:supportsRTL="true"` in your manifest then:
**1. If you want to support just RTL language**, to prevent from changing the direction according to OS language:
Simply just add `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` to parent of all your layouts (Also you can use theme in `styles.xml` [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20685739/5279221)).
Or make an sub activity and extends all your activity from it, then put this code in it's onCreate:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
            configuration.setLayoutDirection(new Locale("fa"));
        getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

But in my mind it's better to set the direction to `rtl` in each layout because you can see how it's going to look without you run the app.

**2. If you want to support both RTL and LTR languages**, of course don't use `android:layoutDirection="rtl/ltr"` in your layouts Because it's direction won't change any way even by code. Because it's going to fix it in the direction `rtl` or `ltr`. so you should use the second one. make an sub activity and extends all your activity from it, then put this code in it (It's just for example):

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
        if (isSlectedLanguageRTL) {
            configuration.setLayoutDirection(new Locale("fa"));
        } else {
            configuration.setLayoutDirection(Locale.ENGLISH);
        }
        getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

And at the end, sorry for my English :)

Comment: Are you sure this completely worked? I want use this for Persian language like you, is this okay for that?

Comment: This Solution is Working for me, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest file and inside the application tag you can add these two lines.

```
<manifest>
    <application
        .
        .
        .
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl" //(replace libraries' Rtl support with ours)
        >
    </application>
</manifest>
```

> Some libraries have support Rtl in their manifest file so if you want
>   to use those libraries you must replace their manifest line of code
>   with yours.

this problem can be solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add something like this in your **App Theme Style**:

```
<item name="android:layoutDirection">ltr</item>
```

This is worked for me.